# Is there a R function or better way to sum rows and columns cumulatively?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Let´s suppose a data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6), C = c(7,8,9), D = c(10,11,12))
```

I want to sum both rows and columns cumulatively, like

```
mysum <- c(sum(df1[1,1:4]), 
       sum(df1[1:2,1:4]),
       sum(df1[1:3,1:4])
          )
```

Any thoughts to improve the code?.
**dplyr** solution? **R** base?
I have thousands of rows and columns.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
mysum <- cumsum(rowSums(df1))

mysum
[1] 22 48 78
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! Of course. Splendid many thanks @neilfws